# How to save HTML pages as one file?

Tags: html, save, archive, webarchive

I want to be able to save / archive HTML pages as one file (without those pesky external folders).

I want the resulting file to contain all styles, images, and links (videos and Flash would be nice, too, but not as crucial).

I want the resulting file to be searchable, and editable.

Microsoft's MHT is one of such tools, but unfortunately, it's not searchable under Linux. MHT is good, but I don't want to be locked under one operating system or one company. What would be a good alternative – or perhaps there's some entirely different solution I wasn't thinking about?

Answer (score 32):

The [SingleFile chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en) is a good solution, there also is [SingleFile for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/) [(open source on Github](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile).

I have also written [my own python tool to solve this problem](https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html)  which I would recommend giving a try.

Answer (score 13):

Viewing and creating MHTML files in current versions of Google Chrome is supported by toggling the "Save Page as MHTML" option on the chrome://flags page.

type chrome://flags in your url box

However, enabling this experimental option disables saving pages as HTML-only or HTML Complete files. From the chrome://flags page:

Comment: The flag now simply adds , not toggles the option for mhtml on Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)

Comment: [Gone](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/7696455?hl=en).

Answer (score 12):

Extending upon [zTrix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292271), I would suggest avoiding the Chrome extension (which did not work for me at all) and instead going with one of these options:

- Node.js: [remy's inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner)

  - Easy to install using `npm`
  - Many options, including flags for disabling minification/compression, maintaining external images, skipping videos, and more.
  - Caveat: (22 September 2017) fails to maintain styling and JavaScript functionality when compiling [Slate builds](https://github.com/lord/slate). This won't affect most people directly, but it means that inliner will probably have issues with other pages. See [this issue](https://github.com/remy/inliner/issues/158)
  - Caveat: no options to "leave things alone": will either minify/uglify CSS/JS or beautify, but will not simply embed original source into HTML.
- Python 2: [zTrix's webpage2html](https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html)

  - More conservative than inliner; works well for most cases.
  - zTrix fixed a bug (that inliner also seems to have) which ensures JavaScript/CSS functionality when compiling [Slate builds](https://github.com/lord/slate). See [this issue](https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html/issues/33). *(updated 29 September 2017)*
  - Can be [converted to Python 3](https://github.com/afeique/compyler) relatively painlessly
  - Caveat: cannot handle CSS `@import`

Comment: Great. Inliner worked for me out of the box. Webpage2Html could not make it. I was trying to convert local files to a single html.

Answer (score 8):

Usually, it's possible to create one HTML file that contains all his common children files (css, jpg, js, svg, ...)
You must rewrite the HTML file by replacing "`src`" attributes' value, "`url()`" functions and insert HTML tag like "`<script></script>`" for JavaScript files, "`<style></style>`" for CSS files and "`<svg></svg>`" for SVG image.

For example a GIF image file in CSS called by the "`url()`" function.

1. download the image from his URL.
2. encode this image into Base64.
3. replace "`url('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TPB_Magnet_Icon.gif')`" by "`url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMALMPAOXl5ewvErW1tebm5oocDkVFRePj47a2ts0WAOTk5MwVAIkcDesuEs0VAEZGRv///yH5BAEAAA8ALAAAAAAMAAwAAARB8MnnqpuzroZYzQvSNMroUeFIjornbK1mVkRzUgQSyPfbFi/dBRdzCAyJoTFhcBQOiYHyAABUDsiCxAFNWj6UbwQAOw')`" with the Base64 encoded GIF image, prefixed by "`data:image/gif;base64,`"

You can do the same thing for the "`src`" attribute's value.
This solution may be used for other binary files. You must adapt the right "`data`" prefix to corresponding to the encoded object.

Comment: Not a one-click solution however good info all the same. Thanks.